# Unix c program to list directories recursively

Tags: c, unix, posix

I am working on a POSIX C learning exercise that involves recursively listing files/folders in a specified directory. The program takes in as arguments of one or more directories. I can list the contents of the initial directory fine but having a problem with the recursion. Is something wrong with the way I am passing in the argument for the recursive function call?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void listdir(char *argv[])
{
  DIR *mydirhandle;

  struct dirent *mydirent;

  struct stat statinfo;

  int n = 1;

  while(argv[n] != NULL)
  {
    if((mydirhandle = opendir(argv[n])) == NULL)
    {
      perror("opendir");
      exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s/\n", argv[n]);

    while((mydirent = readdir(mydirhandle)) != NULL)
    { 
      if((strcmp(mydirent->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(mydirent->d_name, "..") == 0))

      {
        continue;
      }

      else           
      {
        printf("\t%s\n", mydirent->d_name);

         //check if next entry is a directory       
         if(mydirent->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {   
             //is current directory being passed correctly here?
            listdir(mydirent->d_name);
        }
      }        
    }                       
    n++;
    closedir(mydirhandle);
  }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    printf("usage: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  listdir(argv);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning on warnings will show that you're passing the wrong type when making the recursive function call. I would simply make `listdir` take a `char *` argument rather than `char **`, and then use a for loop in `main` to loop over multiple arguments if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

The `d_name` member of `struct dirent` is the basename of the item in question. So, if you're going through a directory like this:

```
.
..
where-is/
   pancakes/
       .
       ..
       house
```

Once you're in `where-is`, you'll try to `listdir("pancakes")` but that won't work because you need to `listdir("where-is/pancakes")`.

You need to combine that with the name of the directory that you're looking before you have something that you can pass to the next `listdir` call.

You'll want to replace things like this:

```
listdir(mydirent->d_name);
```

with things like this:

```
char *next_dir = malloc(strlen(argv[n]) + strlen(mydirent->d_name) + 1 + 1);
sprintf(next_dir, "%s/%s", argv[n], mydirent->d_name);
listdir(next_dir);
free(next_dir);
```

Alternatively, you could [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) into the directories as you enter them and then `chdir` back up when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ftw`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) for this, it calls a given callback on every item of the subtree. This way, you avoid using *explicit* recursion yourself, and your code will get much shorter.