# File system tree traversal

Tags: c, linux, file, filesystems, traversal

I am writing a C program to traverse the file system tree. I am aware of ftw() but would like to do it on my own. The issue is I would like my C program to visit each node(directory/file) without having to do pathlookup(ofcourse done implicitly but want to avoid that too) for each node.

Thanks

Say a directory A has two children B and C. I way to reach each B and C is to read he contents of C and the access B and C with path /A/B and /A/C. But  would like to access B and C with out the path and directly from the reference in A

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: I think I got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035733/unix-c-program-to-list-directories-recursively  in this line "Alternatively, you could chdir into the directories as you enter them and then chdir back up when you're done"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the repeated path lookups and the ugliness (global state and non-thread-safety) of `chdir` by using `openat` and `fdopendir` instead of `opendir` to traverse the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    int spaces = depth*4;

    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    chdir(dir);
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
            if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 || 
                strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
                continue;
            printf("%*s%s/\n",spaces,"",entry->d_name);
            /* Recurse at a new indent level */
            printdir(entry->d_name,depth+1);
        }
        else printf("%*s%s\n",spaces,"",entry->d_name);
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}

/*  Now we move onto the main function.  */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *topdir, pwd[2]=".";
    if (argc != 2)
        topdir=pwd;
    else
        topdir=argv[1];

    printf("Directory scan of %s\n",topdir);
    printdir(topdir,0);
    printf("done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[Link to the original paper](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece537/notes/Files/Examples/printdir.html)